# OVPN client fails to connect, meanwhile an 'identical' one succeeds

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN servers set in 4G remote routers (Teltonika RUT955) and I have the computer of the office that can connect to them succesfully as client.

Now I'm working remotely in another computer where I have pasted the configuration of the office computer and I'm not able to connect to the servers. The office computer is still able to connect, then I disconnect it and try to connect the home computer and it fails.

The OpenVPN handshake gets stuck repeating this line:

```
UDP WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
```

I have found some information on the internet saying that this kind of messages could be due to the server being unable to come back to the client, but I have no idea...

The configuration of the server is (It's configured through web interface):

```
 config webui 'webui'
    option _auth 'tls'

 config openvpn '7365727665725F4F70656E56504E'
    option persist_key '1'
    option port '1194'
    option keepalive '10 120'
    option persist_tun '1'
    option status '/tmp/openvpn-status_server_OpenVPN.log'
    option verb '5'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dev 'tun_s_OpenVPN'
    option _auth 'tls'
    option _tls_cipher 'all'
    option cipher 'AES-256-CBC'
    option client_to_client '1'
    option enable '1'
    option ca '/lib/uci/upload/cbid.openvpn.server_OpenVPN.ca'
    option cert '/lib/uci/upload/cbid.openvpn.server_OpenVPN.cert'
    option key '/lib/uci/upload/cbid.openvpn.server_OpenVPN.key'
    option dh '/lib/uci/upload/cbid.openvpn.server_OpenVPN.dh'
    option server '10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0'
    option name_is_hexed '1'
    list push 'route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0'
    option duplicate_cn '1'
    option auth 'sha1'
    option _tls_auth 'none'
    option client_config_dir '/etc/openvpn/ccd'
```

The configuration file of the clients is:

```
 client
 dev tun
 proto UDP
 remote xxxxxxxxxxx 1194
 resolv-retry infinte
 nobind
 persist-key
 persist-tun
 remote-cert-tls server
 cipher AES-256-CBC
```

In both computers I have a `TAP-Windows Adapter V9` for the VPN. For me both clients are identical, but the one in the office is able to connect, meanwhile the one home isn't.

What can cause this behaviour?

Thanks for your time,

Héctor

EDIT:

logs:

- Succesful client connectiong log: https://pastebin.com/SSn8YAWG
- Server log of the succesful client connection: https://pastebin.com/yEt33n3K
- UNsuccesful client connection log: https://pastebin.com/cHiXPZ8e
- Server log of the UNsuccesful client connection: Empty... no log is registered from this connection attempt.
- UNsuccesful client connection log but with TCP: https://pastebin.com/HvGpfFC3

Tell me if I have forgoted to anonymate something

Comment: Please don't add content to configs - copy & paste as is _(configs are unusable due to the added content)_. To troubleshoot: add `verb 5` to the client config & `verb 4` to the server, restart the server, connect w/ client, and review both the server's & client's OpenVPN logs. General FYIs: EC TLS ciphers are recommended, as they're more efficient than SSL; Encryption over AES128 is unnecessary, as it's uncrackable until at least 2030; SHA1 is not secure - use `SHA512` if OS is x64, else `SHA256` _(tuned config [example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN))_

Comment: First of all sorry for the inconvinience. I will edit the question and put the plain config for the client, but it's going difficult for me to the the same for the server because it's configured through a web interface and I don't believe I have access to the raw config file. Also, thanks for the general FYIs, I'm not an expert and they are useful for me. In the last place, I can't taste VPN again until monday. I will try again then with the new verbosity levels.

Comment: Throughout the day I think I'm going to be able to test again the connection with the new verbosity values, and checking the server logs. Tomorrow at the latest. The router is Teltonika Rut955 that has RutOS (OpenWrt based Linux OS) as OS. I have not found how to change the verbosity of the server log.

Comment: I think your link is for Stunnel, not for OVPN. I don't see any option in the WebUI to change OVPN server verbosity. I'm a novice with VPN's, that's why I have configured it via WebUI instead from SSH. With the current verbosity level, the server doesn't show any log register when the home PC tries to connect, but it does when the office PC connects. For the client side, it was already at verbosity 6. So, there isn't more info from this side, unless you want me to paste the output of verbosity 8, that gives extra information.

Comment: Okey, so the only way to add the verb 4 option to the server config is to completely discard WebUI configuration and substitute it with an standard configuration by file? That, in the other hand, is what you are recommending to me.

Comment: Wow, lot of thanks for the config file! I have found the OpenVPN server config file generated by the webui. (I was searching in /etc/openvpn but it's in /etc/config). I have updated the question with the  real plain configuration. The "problem" is that verb is already set to 5... And I didn't see anything logged from the connections attempts of the home PC.

Comment: I was assuming that since you only posted one line from the log file that the verbosity was set quite low _(I'm going to delete all my comments, but the first)_. Please do the following: Restart the OpenVPN server to clear the server log _(likely located in the root of `/tmp`)_, try to connect with the client, then please copy and paste the server and client logs into your question _(please anonymize them before doing so, removing WAN IPs and any other sensitive info)_. _(With OpenWrt, config files are stored in `/etc/config`, but all other OpenVPN files are usually stored in `/etc/openvpn`)_

Comment: The line I have posted was from the client, not the server. The line that repeats and repeats while is trying to connect unsuccesfuly. I have not found any log of the openvpn under the /tmp folder and subfolders. I read them with logread | grep -i vpn. I have updated my answer with the logs (from succesful and unsuccesful clients)

Comment: You likely have a connection reliability, firewall, or clock issue per error `TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)`. To troubleshoot, change server & client protocol to TCP, retry connection, and review the client log _(if unable to identify the issue, please replace the pastebin with the new client log output and verify if the server log now shows a connection attempt)_. _(General FYI: TCP only has two uses in OpenVPN - troubleshooting or if receiving high packet loss with UDP, as TCP cannot efficiently encapsulate itself.)_

Comment: I have updated the logs with the TCP try. The server log still shows no activity... I don't know how the firewall can be a problem if I'm the client, not the server. For further info, I can connect to the office VPN server that is running on clearOS from home computer, but not to the rut955 server... And the rut955 server can receive connections from the W10 in the office LAN but not from the home W10...

Comment: You're getting an error I've never seen before [`TCP: connect to [AF_INET]public.ip:1194 failed: Unknown error`], so I'd recommend creating a thread on the OpenVPN forum. Since the server isn't registering a connection attempt using TCP, the issue likely either resides on the client or client's router if you're using the exact same config on two clients and the other works _(some ISP's will block commonly exploited ports, which `1194` is, so you may also want to ask your ISP to rule that out)_.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your help anyway. I will try on the OpenVPN forum.